# Is there an equivalent of C# indexer in Java?

Tags: c#, java

I want to do this in Java. Is it possible?

```
public string this[int pos]
    {
        get
       {
            return myData[pos];
        }
        set
       {
            myData[pos] = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No. You can't overload any operators in Java, including indexing. (`String` overloads `+`, but that's baked into the language specification.)

Only arrays support `[]` syntax.

You'd generally write methods instead:

```
public String getValue(int position) {
    return myData[position];
}

public void setValue(int position, String value) {
    myData[position] = value;
}
```

Comment: you're breaking my heart, Java.
Why would anyone give up c# for this?

Answer (score 3):

No, Java does not have anything similar to C#'s indexers or overloaded operators. That is the most likely reason why the function call syntax is used in `String.charAt`, `List.get`, `Map, put`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. AFAIK the usual Java approach to this are `public string get(int pos)` and `public void set(int pos, String value)` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can do directly the same way but you can use `Collection framework` of `Java` which provice similary kind of functionality which you want i suppose. Such as `List`, `Set` etc.